# quadratic equation using processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying to learn programming and thought processing would be fun before going into java. I have learned to do many things in processing like shapes, colors and Boolean expressions but I'm lost in trying to make a program of an equation, particularly the quadratic equation (I've heard it is the best for beginners) but I'm having lots of difficulty trying to do so.  Does anyone know how to do it or produce an example? I'd love to see how programming an equation using processing would work -as all I've seen is examples on java or C.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "program an equation"? What exactly does that look like to you?

Comment: Something that I could input variables that the equation has and in turn get output of roots so input a, b & c and get x1, x2.

Comment: And what have you tried? What exactly about this is confusing you?

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin at  all.  Something about this hasn't clicked yet and I'm not sure what it is I'm just confused on how to do this.  I was thinking of defining each variable a b and c as they are in the formula such as a = sqrt ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing can do pretty much anything a calculator can do. So if you want to write a function that returns the result of the quadratic equation, well, you just write a function that returns the result of the quadratic equation!

```
void setup(){
  println(quadratic(5, 6, 1));
}

float quadratic(float a, float b, float c){
  return (-b + sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
}
```

This is just one of the results, but calculating the other side would be pretty much the same.

Comment: No way that's what i was wondering! I thought there wasn't already a function on it  so I thought I needed to basically tell the program what the quadratic equation is.

Comment: What do you mean by calculating the other side?

Comment: @EdwingChaparro-Chavez The quadratic equations starts with -b **plus or minus**. I've just included the plus half here.

Comment: Right,  I wasn't sure what you meant by that. So is the void setup necessary?  I've never seen it before.

Comment: @EdwingChaparro-Chavez The **setup function** is automatically called by Processing at the beginning of a sketch. Normally it's used for doing things like setting the size of the window. I used it here just so you could actually see the `quadratic()` function being run.

Comment: Awesome. This helps tons now I have an idea of where to begin for electrostatic equations. I understand the code- thanks Kevin Workman!

Comment: Is there a way to make the other side part of the same method? I  get errors using them in the same one

Comment: @EdwingChaparro-Chavez You might consider posting new questions, as StackOverflow isn't really built for discussions in comment sections. You'd either need to create a class that contains both the "plus" and "minus" sides and return that, or add a parameters that determines whether the function returns the "plus" or "minus" side.